# Sabre Instaflights Search One-way getting no results

Tags: api, sabre, sabredav

I am facing an issue in calling Sabre Instaflights Search API Below are the two issues which I am facing.

1. No results if I send only departure date. https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=JFK&destination=LAX&departuredate=2019-01-30&onlineitinerariesonly=N&limit=10&offset=1&eticketsonly=N&sortby=totalfare&order=asc&sortby2=departuretime&order2=asc&pointofsalecountry=US

   Below is the error response which i am getting.

   {
   "status": "Complete",
   "reportingSystem": "RAF",
   "timeStamp": "2019-01-22T13:33:45+00:00",
   "type": "Application",
   "errorCode": "WARN.RAF.APPLICATION",
   "instance": "raf-darhlc005.sabre.com-8080",
   "message": "No results were found"
   }
2. Getting Date range error if the return date above 20 days https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=JFK&destination=LAX&departuredate=2019-01-30&returndate=2019-02-20&onlineitinerariesonly=N&limit=10&offset=1&eticketsonly=N&sortby=totalfare&order=asc&sortby2=departuretime&order2=asc&pointofsalecountry=US

   Below is the error which I am getting.

   {
   "status": "NotProcessed",
   "reportingSystem": "RAF",
   "timeStamp": "2019-01-22T13:43:26+00:00",
   "type": "Validation",
   "errorCode": "ERR.RAF.VALIDATION",
   "instance": "raf-darhlc006.sabre.com-9080",
   "message": "Date range in 'departuredate' and 'returndate' exceeds the maximum allowed"
   }

Please tell me how can fix these errors??